# Wit.ai GET Entity Values Limited to 1000?

Tags: wit.ai

I have an entity that I have populated with multiple thousands of values via the Wit API (https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#post--entities-:entity-id-values-link).

The script to add them seems to have completed successfully, but when I try to retrieve the entity to verify all of it's values, only 1000 are returned.

This appears to be a limit on the GET Entity API call (https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#get--entities-:entity-id-link). Is there a way to retrieve all entity values if there are more than 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the following pagination params in your url:

- limit
- offset

For example limit=1000&offset=1 should retrieve the expression from 1001 to 2000